# How to change speed of a sprite animation on Spritely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been reading the Spritely documentation over and over and I can't find the solution.

I have a sprite made of 4 frames.
I want to animate it endlessly but for each iteration : 1st frame at 99 ms and next 3 frames at 11ms.

How do I achieve the slow down on the first frame?

The syntaxe for doing this isn't clear at all and everything I've tried failed.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
$('#test')
.sprite({fps: 6, no_of_frames: 4})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to find, some of the calls allow speed, like random for instance. So the example they give:

```
$('#bird')
      .sprite({fps: 8, no_of_frames: 3})
      .spRandom({
          top: 70,
          left: 100,
          right: 200,
          bottom: 340,
          speed: 4000,
          pause: 3000
      });
```

allows speed.  The sprite call appears not to. The other speed attribute appears to say on backgrounds, but it might be worth a shot. Their example:

```
$('#trees').pan({fps: 30, speed: 2, dir: 'left'});
```

or

```
$('#hills').spSpeed(20);
```

As far as the second part of your question, sprites can do whatever on N frame by the on_frame function. Again, per their documentation:

```
on_frame: { // note - on_frame is an object not a function
        8: function(obj) { // called on frame 8
            obj.spState(2); // change to state 2 (row 2) on frame 8
        },
        16: function(obj) { // called on frame 16
            obj.spState(3); // change to state 3 (row 3) on frame 16
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but spSpeed() doesn't work at all on .sprite() :( As for your last example, I don't understand what it is for.